# Comparing two strings with SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql

i'm using the regex function with SPARQL.
Is there a function which find a string that have minimum distance from another one?
I mean, i need a function which gives me the most similar word compared with another one.
Actually i pass two variables (these variables take values form two different datasets) and compare just considering these case insensitive. So i need a function that can compare two variables. Does anybosy know anything ?

Comment: Can you clarify your use case a bit?  I'm not quite clear what you're trying to do.  "a function which find a string that have minimum distance from another one" sounds like a function that takes a _single_ argument and returns some word from a fixed set.  But "i pass two variables (…from two different datasets) and compare just considering these case insensitive. …I need a function that can compare two variables." makes it sounds like you want something like `sim(?w1,?w2)` to return a number, so that you can do, e.g., `order by sim(?w1,?w2)`.

Comment: Please post comments as comments, not as answers.  You wrote: "I didn't say that i'm using SPARQL in a OWLIM repository. I want a function that receiving 2 variables it say if those are close enough. When i say close i mean that a word needs the least number of changes to become as the second one so 2 words have to be similar as much as possible. Like when you use regex (e.g regex(?x, ?y, "i")) but with a different comparation."

Comment: What you do you mean "least number of changes", though? Something like `sim("root","book")` requires just two letters to be changed.  But you can't talk about "two" being the least of anything unless you've got something else to compare it to.  Am I correct in understanding that you want to be able to do something like `select ?x ?y where { ... } order by sim(?x,?y) limit 1` so as to get the `?x` and `?y` whose edit distance is minimal over all `?x` and `?y`s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such function in standard SPARQL. However, SPARQL is extensible, so you can add your own functions if you want (of course, at the price of losing portability of your query). For example, see this [tutorial on how to do this in Sesame's SPARQL engine](http://rivuli-development.com/further-reading/sesame-cookbook/creating-custom-sparql-functions/).

I also imagine that some triplestores with extended support for full-text search (like OWLIM, or Virtuoso) may have some built-in support for this kind of thing, but I do not know this for sure.

**Edit**

Assuming you want something like Levenshtein distance, you could have a function `ex:ldistance(?string1, ?string2)` that given two strings outputs the distance. So `ex:ldistance("room", "root")` would return 1, `ex:ldistance("room", "door")` would return 2, and so on. You could then use this to query for a given distance, e.g. to get all strings that are closer than 2 to "room":

```
SELECT ?x ?string1 
WHERE {
       ?x rdfsl:abel ?string1 
       FILTER(ex:ldistance("room", ?string1) < 2)
}
```

or returning all matching strings ordered by their distance:

```
SELECT ?x ?string1 ?ldistance
WHERE {
       ?x rdfsl:abel ?string1 
       BIND ( ex:ldistance("room", ?string1) as ?ldistance)
}
ORDER BY ?ldistance
```

However, as said, the function `ex:ldistance` does not actually exist in SPARQL, so you will need to create it yourself, as an extension.

Comment: I didn't say that i'm using SPARQL in a OWLIM repository.
I want a function that receiving 2 variables it say if those are close enough. When i say close i mean that a word needs the least number of changes to become as the second one so 2 words have to be similar as much as possible. Like when you use regex (e.g regex(?x, ?y, "i")) but with a different comparation.

Comment: Yes. I understood that. Presumably you want something like Levenshtein or Jaro-Winkler. To repeat: there is no such function in standard SPARQL, but some triplestores may have some extensions for it - or you can create your own extension.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of how such a function might be used in SPARQL.

Comment: Details on Virtuoso Full Text index support can be found at http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/sparqlextensions.html