# Checking if last word of string is (case-insensitively) contained in another string

Tags: regex, sparql

I'm using the `regex` SPARQL function and I pass two variables to it in this way:

```
FILTER regex(?x, ?y, "i")
```

I would like, for example, to compare these two strings: `Via de' cerretani` and `via dei Cerretani`. by extracting the significant word of the first string, which is usually the last word, `cerretani` in this case, and check if it's contained in the second string. As you can see, I pass these two strings as variables.  How can I do this?

Comment: So, do you want to compare, or extract, or check if one is contained in the other, or all three? What, exactly, is the question here? If you can do this using just the SPARQL REGEX function? Then the answer is no. 

It might help if you showed an example of what you're trying to achieve: some sample RDF data, a (full) example SPARQL query, and the output that you're hoping to get from that query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing two strings with SPARQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773134/comparing-two-strings-with-sparql)

Comment: @user2637212 You already asked an essentially identical question and got an answer that it is not possible with standard SPARQL and you would need to write your own extension function(s) to do this

Comment: @RobV I thought the same thing at first about this question being a duplicate of that one, but this is actually much more specific, and can be answered.  The other question asked about a function to find a string that's similar to another by returning (I think) an edit distance.  This one is much more specific: "can I check whether the last word of a string is contained (case insensitively) in another?"  I'd say that they're related, but that this is ***not*** a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry i didn't want to duplicate the question. Actually since there is no function in SPARQL which does what i asked in the other post i wrote something more specific. By the way, the answer of Joshua does exactly what i want. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I though that this was a duplicate of your earlier question, [Comparing two strings with SPARQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19773134/1281433), but that's asking about a function that returns an edit distance.  The task here is much more specific:  Check whether the last word of a string is contained (case insensitively) in another string.  As long as we take your specification that

> the significant word of the string … is usually the last one

strictly and *always* use only the last word of the string (since there's no way to determine, in general, what the “significant word of the string” is), we can do this.  You won't end up using the `regex` function, though.  Instead we'll use `replace`, `contains`, and `lcase` (or `ucase`).

The trick is that we can get the last word of a string `?x` by using `replace` to remove all the words by the last one (and the space before the one), and can then use `strcontains` to check whether this last word is contained in the other string.  Using case normalization functions (in the following code, I used `lcase`, but `ucase` should work, too) we can do the containment check case insensitively.

```
select ?x ?y ?lastWordOfX ?isMatch ?isIMatch where { 
  # Values gives us some test data.  It just means that ?x and ?y
  # will be bound to the specified values.  In your final query, 
  # these would be coming from somewhere else.
  values (?x ?y) {
    ("Via de' cerretani" "via dei Cerretani")
    ("Doctor Who" "Who's on first?")
    ("CaT" "The cAt in the hat")
    ("John Doe" "Don't, John!")
  }

  # For "the significant word of the string which is
  # usually the last one", note that the "all but the last word" 
  # is matched by the pattern ".* ".  We can replace "all but the
  # last word to leave just the last word.  (Note that if the
  # pattern doesn't match, then the original string is returned.
  # This is good for us, because if there's just a single word, 
  # then it's also the last word.)
  bind( replace( ?x, ".* ", "" ) as ?lastWordOfX )

  # When you check whether the second string contains the first, 
  # you can either leave the cases as they are and have a case
  # sensitive check, or you can convert them both to the same 
  # case and have a case insensitive match.
  bind( contains( ?y, ?lastWordOfX ) as ?isMatch )
  bind( contains( lcase(?y), lcase(?lastWordOfX) ) as ?isIMatch )
}
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| x                   | y                    | lastWordOfX | isMatch | isIMatch |
=================================================================================
| "Via de' cerretani" | "via dei Cerretani"  | "cerretani" | false   | true     |
| "Doctor Who"        | "Who's on first?"    | "Who"       | true    | true     |
| "CaT"               | "The cAt in the hat" | "CaT"       | false   | true     |
| "John Doe"          | "Don't, John!"       | "Doe"       | false   | false    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

That might look like a lot of code, but's because there are comments, and the last word is bound to another variable, and I've included both case sensitive and case insensitive matches.  When you're actually using this, it will be much shorter.  For instance, to select only those `?x` and `?y` that match in this way:

```
select ?x ?y {
  values (?x ?y) {
    ("Via de' cerretani" "via dei Cerretani")
    ("Doctor Who" "Who's on first?")
    ("CaT" "The cAt in the hat")
    ("John Doe" "Don't, John!")
  }
  filter( contains( lcase(?y), lcase(replace( ?x, ".* ", "" ))))
}
```

```
----------------------------------------------
| x                   | y                    |
==============================================
| "Via de' cerretani" | "via dei Cerretani"  |
| "Doctor Who"        | "Who's on first?"    |
| "CaT"               | "The cAt in the hat" |
----------------------------------------------
```

It's true that

```
contains( lcase(?y), lcase(replace( ?x, ".* ", "" )))
```

is a bit longer than something like

regex( ?x, ?y, "some-special-flag" )

but I think it's fairly short.  If you're willing to use the last word of `?x` as a regular expression (which probably isn't a good idea, because you don't know that it doesn't contain special regular expression characters) you could even use:

```
regex( replace( ?x, ".* ", "" ), ?y, "i" )
```

but I suspect that it's probably faster to use `contains`, since `regex` has many more things to check.

Comment: I have to ask something else about regex in SPARQL. Should i ask here or should i do a new question? ... sorry about this but i'm not so familiar with stackoverflow yet

Comment: If what you want to ask is a clarification on something in this answer, ask it here. Otherwise, ask it as a new question (you can include a link to this question if it is related).  And: no problem, Stackoverflow takes some getting used to :)